# How do I make a Java JAR file executable in Linux Mint?

Tags: jar

This is the notice I get:

```
The file '/home/heart/Phantombot/PhantomBot-2.4.1/PhantomBot.jar' 
is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied
from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run. 
For more details, read about the executable bit.
```

Basically, the JAR file doesn't have the necessary permission to run. How do I give it this permission?

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /home/heart/Phantombot/PhantomBot-2.4.1/PhantomBot.jar`

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To add executable bit to a file, use this construction:

```
chmod +x /path/to/file
```

The command for your `jar` file is

```
chmod +x /home/heart/Phantombot/PhantomBot-2.4.1/PhantomBot.jar
```

if you'are owner of the file.

If you aren't owner of the file, use leading `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/heart/Phantombot/PhantomBot-2.4.1/PhantomBot.jar
```